# SQL-Server join issue when filtering on a freetext (vchar) column

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck with a SQL Server view I am trying to create. The view returns a list of resources that are assigned to a project along with a few other details such as contract information.
I'm having issues with the resource_contracts table though because I'm stuck dealing with what is essentially a free-text field.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
                CONCAT(RTRIM(res.first_name),' ', RTRIM(res.surname)) AS fullname ,
        res.main_res_id                                                           ,
        res.resource_id                                                           ,
        res.resource_typ                                                          ,
        res.status                                                                ,
        rel.rel_value                                                             ,
        asn.booking_project        AS project                                            ,
        asn.booking_project_descr  AS project_descr                                      ,
        asn.assignment_position    AS position                                           ,
        asn.date_from              AS commencement_date                                  ,
        DATEADD(DAY,1,asn.date_to) AS end_date                                           ,
        con.comment_fx
FROM resourcees res
INNER JOIN resource_relations rel
    ON
            res.main_res_id = rel.resource_id
    AND     rel.date_to    >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
    AND     res.client      = rel.client
LEFT OUTER JOIN resource_relations cc
    ON
            res.client      = cc.client
    AND     res.resource_id = cc.resource_id
    AND     cc.rel_attr_id  = 'C1'
    AND     res.date_to BETWEEN cc.date_from AND     cc.date_to
    AND     cc.status = 'N'
INNER JOIN relation_values ar2
    ON
            cc.rel_value = ar2.dim_value
    AND     ar2.client   = res.client
INNER JOIN assignments asn
    ON
            res.main_res_id = asn.resource_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN resource_contracts con
    ON
            con.dim_value     = res.main_res_id
    AND     res.client        = con.client
    AND     con.comment_fx LIKE '%CONAU%'
    AND     con.date_to_fx   >= asn.date_to
WHERE
        asn.booking_project = '123456'
ORDER BY
        fullname
```

I guess the above looks fairly large. It's the last join causing the issue for reference.

The resource_contracts table contacts three columns. I hate this setup, but it's outside of my control unfortunately.

- date_from_fx = DATETIME
- date_to_fx = DATETIME
- comment_fx = VCHAR 255

It's used to record contracts date from and date to, and a free text field that could contain anything annoyingly. Sample values might be "CONAU SPP" or "CONSG ABC" etc..

I'm stuck on the comment_fx field above however.

I specifically want to see contracts containing CONAU, or return a NULL value if they do not have one that meets the date require, or do not have a row at all. Unfortunately this logic is getting mixed up any other contract they have such as "CONSG ABC"
No matter what join I apply, I either can see all the resources with the contract required, or duplicate rows with null values and a mix of the non-applicable contracts. I guess I am missing something simple

Ultimately I need to produce a list of resources that are assigned to a project, but do not have the required contract (CONAU), that list will trigger another process that I've already sorted out.

**Updated:**
Let me show you the data that gets returned if we removed the resource_contracts table causing my issues:
[Data result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5zLj.png)

Apologies, I couldn't format the table into something that resembled a table to paste here.

Here is the data from the contracts table:
[contracts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0nLp.png)

There's kind of multiple things I want to do here but I'll simplify it into a single one.
I'm trying to send a parameter to the query, 'CONAU' for example. So it will return all resources that do NOT have a valid row containing the string CONAU.
Problem is, they might have other rows like CONSG, or no rows at all.

During my attempts I would often get the wrong rows to show or when using ISNULL in the SELECT part, I would get null rows and duplicated data.

The conditions could be inverted but I'm trying to learn this myself.

SQL fiddle too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7558f/2

Comment: Do you mean a `varchar`?

Comment: Unfortunately it's pretty hard to understand the problem from your description. Could you add a small sample of the data that you're getting back, that illustrates the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: varchar yes sorry, mind is a jumbled mess of languages.. I'll put together some sample data, i had to cleanse it a lot before posting the above originally.

Comment: Your combination of inner and outer joins suggests you don't really have a good handle on your schema. You inner join to ar2 yet that join depends on cc - to which you outer join. Use of distinct is often a kludge to solve a logic problem in a query. I suggest you start over by building and testing your logic table by table. If you have problems, posting here with a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) will enable others to provide useful suggestions.

Comment: I've updated the question to include data examples from the tables. The other joins are fine and achieve the result desired. But I do understand that I'm being result driven at the moment, rather than looking at the best solution perhaps.

Comment: This might help as well, I changed it around a bit to remove some stuff http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7558f/2  My live production query is quite a bit more complicated but I wanted to focus on the specific problem I can replicate without a ton of other data

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE
    asn.booking_project = '123456'
    AND con.comment_fx LIKE '%CONAU%'
```

To the trailing end.

Comment: That doesn't change anything unfortunately, same result.